# Updated android studio and Cannot find build tools 22 to add as dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, android-appcompat

I updated android studio and build tools to the latest version. Now I want to add AppCompat v7 version 22.0.1 dependency to my project.

I cannot find it in the **Project structure** Dependency list.

Answer (score 1):

**The app-compat 22.0.1 doesn't exist.**

You can use in `build.gradle` one of these:

```
dependencies{

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 23
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 22
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 21
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Project Structure**, in your **module**'s item, you have no "Dependencies" tab?

In your build.gradle, 'dependencies', add just this line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'
```

It should work...

Comment: It has got Dependencies tab but only appcompat v7 23 is showing. And not 22.0.1

Comment: Its now showing this error --> Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: But I cannot install the required Repository. Its showing empty package there

Comment: Did you check in your build.gradle which version of appcompat is it?

Comment: build.gradle has com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1 . I added it after your answer.

Comment: Are you sure that your SDK is updated? For this, please open your SDK manager and check if your SDK Build tools 22.0.1 is installed. :) let me know if it's ok